# How can I OnPropertyChanged of BindableBase without the optional parameter?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, prism

In the documentation for `OnPropertyChanged`, MSDN says about the propertyName parameter:

> Name of the property used to notify listeners. This value is optional and can be provided automatically when invoked from compilers that support `CallerMemberNameAttribute`.

Now I'm pretty sure my compiler supports `CallerMemberNameAttribute`, as it is used elsewhere in our codebase. However, it gives an error when I try to call it without this parameter.

> No Overload for method 'OnPropertyChanged' takes 0 arguments.

Am I missing something, or could this be a bug in Prism?

If it helps, I have:

- Visual Studio 2015
- Microsoft.Practices.Prism.Mvvm Version 1.1.1.0

A sample of code that gives the error is

```
public Unit Unit
{
    get
    {
        var unit = GetUnit();
        if (unit == null && PropertySettings != null) return PropertySettings.GetDefaultUnit();

            return unit;
        }
        set
        {
            SetUnit(value);
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }
```

This is a property from a class the inherits from BindableBase

Comment: What error do you observe?

Comment: would you please share with us the peace of code that gives error ?

Comment: Right click on OnPropertyChanged, select "go to implementation", paste what you find into an [edit].

Answer (score 1):

can you verify this:
1. CallerMemberName is actually present

```
protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
        {
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
```

2. I f you are able to use  C#6.0 as part of .NET 4.5.3; try the ***nameof*** Operator

Comment: I'm wagering BindableBase doesn't have `([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)`

Comment: @Will That is a losing bet: `protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName]string propertyName = null)` https://github.com/PrismLibrary/Prism/blob/a60d38013c02b60807e9287db9ba7f7506af0e84/Source/Prism/Mvvm/BindableBase.cs

Comment: @R.Richards Not necessarily.  Nothing says he's actually referencing *that* implementation.

Comment: @Will That is true. I was just scanning the question for a version number... none.

Answer (score 0):

You're using a package that is no longer supported "Microsoft.Practices.Prism.Mvvm Version 1.1.1.0".  The link you provided is not the source code to the package you are using.  The NuGet package you should be using is Prism.Core which contains the Prism.dll and uses the source in which you linked to.

Comment: Okay, so I take it that support for `CallerMemberName` was added in Prism 6.0, and does not exist in Prism 5.0?